# What do we call the open part at the back of a snack pack?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

I'm writing a packing procedure report. And I don't know what the open part at the back of a pack should be called. Does anyone know this?

[image: packing]

Comment: Can you elaborate or include a picture of what you're referring to?  An open part at the back of a pack isn't ringing any bells as to what you might be talking about.

Comment: @fixer1234 picture added (y)

Comment: This one is still escaping me.  On something like a pouch made from a sheet of paper or plastic film, the material is formed into a tube, which is flattened into a pouch,  and then the top and bottom of the tube are sealed to hold the contents.  Where the sides were joined to form the tube, it is often sealed a short distance from the edge.  The material between the seal and the edge becomes a flap that is folded flat against the pouch, usually running down the back of the pouch.  Is that flap the part you're referring to?

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, that is

Comment: I'm not familiar with a specific technical name for that and if there was, and you're writing for non-technical people, they might not be familiar with the term.  I'd be more inclined to just describe it.  Maybe refer to it as "the flap running down the back".

Comment: @fixer1234 thank you, but i prefer a specific name cause this report is for company partner =)). anw, tks

Comment: Perhaps the "back seam"?

Comment: seems legit. i will use it then. tks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the opening in the back of the pack is one that can be *opened* and *closed*, especially if the packing is made of plastic, it [could be called](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ziplock) a **ziplock**.

> having an interlocking groove and ridge that form a tight seal when pressed together a ziplock plastic bag

If it's a permanent fixture that must be broken to open and cannot be refastened, I would call it a **seal**.

> 2 a :  something that secures (as a wax seal on a document)
>
> b :  a closure that must be broken to be opened and that thus reveals tampering

I would take a look at google image searches of these terms and see if they fit with what you're referring to.

Comment: tks, i supposed to use "seal" at first but i need something more detail to tell partner exactly which part i'm talking about (top, bottom, back). "back seam" seems a legit answer atm =)). tks for spending time (y)